# Find the diophantine-equations $3x(x^2+2)=y^2$ integer solution

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

> Let $x,y$ be positive integers, such that 
>   $$3x(x^2+2)=y^2$$
>   since
>   $$3\cdot 1(1^2+2)=3\times 3=9=3^2$$
>   $$3\cdot 2(2^2+2)=6\cdot 6=36=6^2$$
>   $$24\cdot 3(24^2+2)=72\cdot 578=204^2$$
>   so I have found three solutions $(x,y)=(1,3),(2, 6),(24, 204)$
>
> Are there any other solutions?

**ADD:**  In fact $$LHS=(x-1)^3+x^3+(x+1)^3$$

Comment: There's a vast literature on finding integer points on elliptic curves. It's very likely that this curve has been analyzed, although I don't know a reference offhand. In any case, you should add tags for nt.number-theory and for elliptic-curve.

Comment: @JoeSilverman True, but most software (Magma, Sage), likes $y^2 = f(x),$ where $f(x)$ is a *monic* polynomial. If you would tell the OP how to transform his question to that form, I am sure s/he would be delighted.

Comment: You can multiply both sides by $9$. Then set $X = 3x$ and $Y = 3y$ and get $Y^2 = f(X)$, where $f$ is monic.

Comment: @JeremyRouse You get $X((X/3)^2+2) = Y^2,$ So setting $\mathfrak{Y} = 3 Y,$ we finally get $X^3 + 18 X = \mathfrak{Y}^2.$

Comment: Whereup Magma says:

> IntegralPoints(E);
[ (0 : 0 : 1), (3 : -9 : 1), (6 : 18 : 1), (72 : -612 : 1) ]
[ <(0 : 0 : 1), 1>, <(3 : -9 : 1), 1>, <(6 : 18 : 1), 1>, <(72 : -612 : 1), 1> ]

Answer (score 4):

See: [A Diophantine Equation](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C9FFD20B04DBB385C60BCAF6694CD08D/S0017089500006030a.pdf/a-diophantine-equation.pdf) by J. W. S. Cassels

The only solutions are $x = 0, 1, 2, 24$.

Comment: ...as confirmed by magma, as in my comment.